# How to use AppProject with app of apps patern to restrict destination namespace?

Tags: argocd

Trying to restrict destination namespace with ArgoCD AppProject. While using AppProject with app of apps patern, child apps giving error "namespace argocd is not permitted in project "argocd-test". Am I missing something? Any suggestions would be apprciated on how to fix the issue.

Created AppProject with destincation namespace, server. Configured parent or root application and child applicationto use that project but child application is failing.

Comment: You'd need to show us some concrete code (your Application/ApplicationSet definition) but sounds like you're trying to create resources in argocd namespace but you didn't allow that in the `AppProject`.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% on my answer, it would be better if you share your yaml, here is what works for me:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: AppProject
metadata:
  name: operations
  namespace: argocd # this ns is a must, as the project must be deployed in the same ns where argocd lives
spec:
  description: System-level cluster configurations
  sourceRepos:
    - '*'
  destinations:
    - namespace: '*'# this allows all ns, to disallow certain ns use '!ns' for example namespace: '!istio-system'
      server: '*'
  clusterResourceWhitelist:
    - group: '*'
      kind: '*'
```